# ms access vba sending Email using outlook .. stay in outbox

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-access-2007

i am using this code to send an email using outlook, but the problem is that I must open outlook then the messages will be sent.

i used .display but the problem still the same.

Thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub btnSend_Click()

On Error GoTo errHandelrs

Dim oOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim oeMailitem As MailItem
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim CustmrEmail As String
Dim n As Integer

If oOutlook Is Nothing Then
Set oOutlook = New Outlook.Application
End If
Set oeMailitem = oOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With oeMailitem
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select *from tbl")

 If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
 rs.MoveFirst
 Do Until rs.EOF
 If IsNull(rs!Email) Then
 rs.MoveNext
 Else
 CustmrEmail = CustmrEmail & rs!Email & ";"
     .To = CustmrEmail
     rs.MoveNext
     End If
     Loop
Else
     MsgBox "nO bOdy"
End If
    .CC = ""
    .Subject = "mYSUbject"
    For n = 0 To Me.list3.ListCount - 1
    .Attachments.Add (Me.list3.ItemData(n))
    Next n
    .Send

End With
Exit_ErrHandelrs:
Exit Sub
errHandelrs:
MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
Resume Exit_ErrHandelrs
End Sub
```

Comment: There is no such thing on SO as pinging to bring the post up again, as other forums have.

Comment: Was my question clear ??

Answer (score 0):

You can Sync the account to ensure the email is sent (and new email is received). Send/Receive settings can be modified for Outlook to change its behavior in interactive use.

```
Dim oSyncObjects As Outlook.SyncObjects
Dim i As Long


Set oSyncObjects = oOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").SyncObjects

For i = 1 To oSyncObjects.Count
    OSyncObjects.Item(i).Start
Next
```

Comment: thanks MikeC for reply but unfortunately the situation still the same .any other idea ?

Comment: I used Shell function at the beginning of my code like this .. is it OK ?? Shell ("outlook.exe")

Comment: Your posted code shows `Set oOutlook = New Outlook.Application`?! If you are Shelling it out, how were you able to process SyncObjects according to the code I posted?

Comment: Thank you MIceC ,but i told you that the situation is the same with Syncobjects .mails stay in outbox and i must open the outlook, but with shell its ok now , but i need your advice if there is any thing i dont know about shell.